# How to create a unique style for toggle buttons with properties changed dynamically in code

Tags: wpf, styles

I would like to create a style for all toggle buttons in my application. They have all the same behavior except they load different images. My idea was change the resources "ToggleButtonImg_Disabled", "ToggleButtonImg_IsMouseOver", "ToggleButtonImg_IsPressed" and "ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked" in code, when the button is pressed.
However it's not working... Can someone help me! Thanks in advance!

XAML

```
<Image Width="20" Source="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_Disabled" />
<Image Width="20" Source="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsMouseOver" />
<Image Width="20" Source="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsPressed" />
<Image Width="20" Source="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked" />



<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_Disabled}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border 
                  x:Name="CustomControlTemplate"  
                  CornerRadius="2" 
                  BorderThickness="1">
                      <ContentPresenter 
                        Margin="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsMouseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsPressed}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

CODE

//Set the images of the button when the button is pressed

```
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.UriSource = new Uri(@"Resources/Images/icon_play.png", UriKind.Relative);
                img.EndInit();
                _receiver.Resources["ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked"] = img;
```

My code updated (only XAML):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_Disabled}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Image x:Name="CustomControlTemplate" 
                       Width="20" 
                       Source="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png"
                />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="CustomControlTemplate" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsMouseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="CustomControlTemplate" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsPressed}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CustomControlTemplate" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an Image-Control in your ControlTemplate where you want and change the setter of the Triggers to:

```
<Setter TargetName="imageName" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource resourceKey}" />
```

EDIT: Instead of Images, use BitmapImages as Source:

```
<BitmapImage Width="20" UriSource="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_Disabled" />
<BitmapImage Width="20" UriSource="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsMouseOver" />
<BitmapImage Width="20" UriSource="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsPressed" />
<BitmapImage Width="20" UriSource="Resources/Images/icon_stop.png" x:Key="ToggleButtonImg_IsChecked" />
```

Comment: Hi Florian! It is not working :( The error is "Cannot find the Template Property 'Content'"

Comment: Sry my fault, I forgot to change the Property, I editted my answer.

Comment: I don't know if i did something wrong but i get this error now:  "You can not associate the object type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'."}

Comment: The Source of an image cannot be of type Image, but BitmapImage should work, see my edit.